# Want to override special price end date in list.phtml

Tags: magento-1.8, overrides, special-price, list.phtml

i am trying to override special price start/end date time.
i have done in view.phtml, but in list.phtml it is not applied when i set special price end date in admin panel.
What i did wrong.

Can anyone help me in this case.

Thanks in advance.

**Updates:**

- i have overridden list.phtml, price.phtml and view.phtml in templates
- overridden Price.php in Mage->Catalog->Model->Product->Type

Now the changes i made are applied in view.phtml, but in list.phtml it is not appiled.

And i want to **override** the **special price end date**.

Comment: can you add more details by editing question. what you have changed and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sure Charlie...

Comment: there is file called `price .phtml`, look into that, it may solve your problem

Comment: Yes i have checked with that but it didnt help me

Comment: where i can edit the special price end date in code(for list.phtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue...
to override special price start and end date, 
we have to override **Product.php** in **Mage->Catalog->Model**

Here find the **getFinalPrice($qty=null)** function and set from date and to date

like

$toDate='your date';

$fromDate='your date';